# Call Another Source File

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm building a program(in 16-Bits) using Assembly(nasm as the assembler), but as I love to have things organized in different source files. Let's think I have 2 sources, one called `main.asm` and another one called `source2.asm`, but I want to call the `source1.asm` content in the middle of `main.asm`. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GLOBAL`](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoc5.html#section-5.5) and [`EXTERN`](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoc5.html#section-5.4).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `%include` directive. See nasm manual [section 4.5](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoc4.html)

Comment: But if I want just to call a label that is defined at `source2.asm`?